# Array does not show all objects after setting

Tags: java, arrays, crud

I am VERY new to Java so bear with me. This is basically only my 3rd assignment.
I'm supposed to create a CRUD operation, using an array of objects in "Dog" Class. My main issue here is when I try to "get" the attributes, I only get the first element of the array, not the second and third.
Not sure what code I'm supposed to provide so I will just paste these two parts.

```
 Dog [] dogList = new Dog [20];
        for (int ctr = 0; ctr < dogList.length; ctr++)
            dogList[ctr] = new Dog();
    
    dogList[0].setDogID("H1");
    dogList[0].setDogName("Nike");
    dogList[0].setDogAge(8);
    dogList[0].setDogBreed("Labrador");
    dogList[0].setDogColor("Black");
    dogList[0].setDogGender("Male");
    dogList[0].setContactPerson("Sara Karlsson");
    dogList[0].setTelephone("07012345678");
    dogList[0].setNumberOfHours(5);
    dogList[0].setMiscInfo("-");
    dogList[1].setDogID("H2");
    dogList[1].setDogName("Cookie");
    dogList[1].setDogAge(3);
    dogList[1].setDogBreed("Coccker spaniel");
    dogList[1].setDogColor("White and black");
    dogList[1].setDogGender("Female");
    dogList[1].setContactPerson("Kalle Ek");
    dogList[1].setTelephone("07012345679");
    dogList[1].setNumberOfHours(49);
    dogList[1].setMiscInfo("-");
    dogList[2].setDogID("H3");
    dogList[2].setDogName("Lara");
    dogList[2].setDogAge(5);
    dogList[2].setDogBreed("French Bulldog");
    dogList[2].setDogColor("Black");
    dogList[2].setDogGender("Female");
    dogList[2].setContactPerson("Pelle Andersson");
    dogList[2].setTelephone("07012345671");
    dogList[2].setNumberOfHours(30);
    dogList[2].setMiscInfo("-");
```

This is the case where I'm supposed to show the full list of array I already set:

```
case "E":
     {
    System.out.println("These are all the dogs on the list:\n");
    for (int i1=0; i1<=i; i1++)    
        System.out.println("Dog ID:"+dogList[i1].getDogID() + "\n" +
                            "Dog Name:"+dogList[i1].getDogName()+ "\n" +
                            "Age:"+dogList[i1].getDogAge() + "\n"+ 
                            "Dog Breed:"+dogList[i1].getDogBreed() + "\n"+
                            "Dog Color:"+dogList[i1].getDogColor() + "\n"+
                            "Dog Gender:"+dogList[i1].getDogGender() + "\n"+
                            "Contact Person:"+dogList[i1].getContactPerson() + "\n"+
                            "Telephone:"+dogList[i1].getTelephone() + "\n"+
                            "Number of hours:"+dogList[i1].getNumberOfHours() + "\n"+
                            "Misc. Information:"+dogList[i1].getMiscInfo() 
                            + "\n**************************************************\n");
    
    }
    break;
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: what value does i have? that is probably your mistake. replace i by dogList.length and add a null check to verify if the element has been entered.

Comment: the loop condition in the lower part says that `i1` will be incremented until it reaches `i`. What is `i`?

Comment: i is supposed to be just the elements that are in use. I didn't use the dogList.length coz I didn't want them to show all 20 empy arrays. So how do I do the null check?

Comment: @S.J. then it seems that i is not incremented and is 0. Try printing the value of i (or debug the code) to find out

Comment: The i is in fact 0. How do I fix that?

Comment: Set ``i = 20;//as you have 20 dogs``

Comment: Thanks. But that displays a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 20 out of bounds.

Comment: Can someone tell me how to add the null check? Thanks!

Comment: And ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException seems strange, given the code shown. Regardless, `i = dogList.length;` should resolve it.

Comment: @VGR no, it shouldn't, since he uses <= instead of <

Comment: @Stultuske Ah yes, you’re right, I missed that.